# How can I improve my memory leak question?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked a question about tracing the source of a debug output in some specific C++/CLI situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862231/how-to-trace-the-source-of-a-crt-debug-memory-leak-output-from-managed-c-sharp-c). It received a lot of down/closing votes without explanations, and when I asked for some I was told that I wasn't asking a specific question, that I showed no effort in solving it myself and that this has nothing to do with C++/CLI and it's definitely a problem with the native code that's being wrapped.

Obviously if so many people think my question is bad, there's probably something I'm missing or not communicating right. I did ask specifically if there's a way to trace the source of these object dumps from the managed code (and "No" is a perfectly good answer), I did spend several days on this issue before going to SO and I mentioned several steps I took in order to solve the problem. Also, there was no problem with the native code at all.

I saw many other questions that were actually upvoted a lot\, and I can't tell the difference between my question and theirs:

- [How to solve Private bytes (Native memory) leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900433/how-to-solve-private-bytes-native-memory-leak?rq=1)
- [How to find memory leak in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588291/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-wpf-application?rq=1)
- [dealing with an unmanaged dll with a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500644/dealing-with-an-unmanaged-dll-with-a-memory-leak)

I think that if anything my question had more details and was more specific than something like "How to find a memory leak".

How can I avoid these situations and improve my questions in the future?

Comment: Your question is not particularly bad and your answer is (slightly) interesting. Just bad luck with the people visiting, I think, don't worry too much...

Comment: Using the correct tags on a question is super-duper important.  Using so many language tags got it visited by many dozens of people, 98% of them had no idea whatsoever what it is about.  Aiming high.  Research is a basic requirement to know how to tag a question.  Fixed, ought to slow down the voting.